# How to get the preceding sentence after "\v"?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Here's my text file:

```
\v 1 The book of the generation of Jesus Christ,
the son of David, the son of Abraham.
\v 2 Abraham begat Isaac; and Isaac begat Jacob; and Jacob begat Judas and his brethren;
\v 3 And Judas begat Phares and Zara of Thamar;
and Phares begat Esrom; and Esrom begat Aram;
\v 4 And Aram begat Aminadab; and Aminadab begat Naasson; and Naasson begat Salmon;
\v 5 And Salmon begat Booz of Rachab; and Booz begat Obed of Ruth; and Obed begat Jesse;
```

I want to capture the sentence from `\v` to the next `\v`.

Here's my code idea so far:

```
mylines = []
pattern = re.compile(r"(\\v)|(.*?)|(\\v)")
with open ('file.txt', 'rt', encoding='utf-8') as myfile:
    for line in myfile:
        if pattern.search(line) != None:
            mylines.append(line.rstrip('\n'))

for element in mylines:
    print(element)
```

The problem is the code does not return the required sentence, instead it returns the whole text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with a regex "[positive look-ahead assertion](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html#lookahead-assertions)" that specifies that the match continues until the contained expression is encountered (but doesn't capture it) — which happens in this case to be another `\v`.

Since the pattern can cross and contain multiple lines, the entire text file is read in and all matches are found in a single call to the compiled pattern's [`findall()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.Pattern.findall) method.

To make how the expression operates clearer, I've included a "verbose" version of it that explains what the various parts are doing (as well as the more common and succinct version).

```
import re

filename = 'vfile.txt'

# Compact version of regex.
#pattern = re.compile(r"^\\v[ ](.*?)(?=\\v|\Z)", re.DOTALL | re.MULTILINE)

# Long version.
pattern = re.compile(r"""^\\v[ ]      # \v followed by a space at start of a line.
                         (.*?)        # Any character, zero or more times (non-greedy)
                         (?=\\v|\Z)   # \v or end-of-string (non-capturing)
                      """,
                      re.DOTALL |     # Makes '.' also match newlines
                      re.MULTILINE |  # Changes what '^' and '$' mean.
                      re.VERBOSE)     # Ignore whitespace in the pattern
                                      # (except when in a character class),

# Read whole file.
with open(filename, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as myfile:
    text = myfile.read()

# Create a list of all matches.
matches = pattern.findall(text)

# Find the list.
for i, match in enumerate(matches, 1):
    print(f'#{i}:\n{match}')
```

Output from processing your text file:

```
#1:
1 The book of the generation of Jesus Christ,
the son of David, the son of Abraham.

#2:
2 Abraham begat Isaac; and Isaac begat Jacob; and Jacob begat Judas and his brethren;

#3:
3 And Judas begat Phares and Zara of Thamar;
and Phares begat Esrom; and Esrom begat Aram;

#4:
4 And Aram begat Aminadab; and Aminadab begat Naasson; and Naasson begat Salmon;

#5:
5 And Salmon begat Booz of Rachab; and Booz begat Obed of Ruth; and Obed begat Jesse;
```

Comment: Amazing, this works so well. Thank you sir.

Comment: I'm just curious martineau, is it possible to do this without regular expression? How would that look?

Comment: Yes, it could be done without using regular expressions, which are just search pattern-driven [Regular Language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_language) parsers after all. There's also likely more than one way to implement one "by hand" (via a [Finite State Machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine), for example), but frankly I'm not that interested in pursuing the topic further. Suggest you try doing it yourself—or even ask another question and specify that you don't want to use regular expressions to do it (showing you own attempt, of course).

Answer (score 0):

I would just read the entire file and split by `\v`. I also replace the newline char with a blank space, in case it occurs in the middle of the sentence.

```py
f = open("file.txt");

lines = f.read().split("\\v")

lines = [s.replace("\n", " ") for s in lines]

print (lines);
```

Comment: Thanks David, the result isn't quite what I'm looking for.